# show validation message after user enters invalid value and focused out and then on keyup,using knockout validation

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am using knockout validation to validate the data before updating in db. 
I am not so familiar with knockout validation.
"valueUpdate" in data-bind for an input box is with "afterkeydown", for which, each time i am giving some invalid value the message is coming up. 
But I want to show the message after user first time focused out from the input box. After that I want to show the message on key up.
If I can set the valueUpdate after focus out from view model, this may help.
Since I am having other bindings in data-bind, I can't just add data-bind attribute from vm.
I checked[this link](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration).

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Can you offer some of your code?

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/KHFn8/5726/ . else try forking my fiddle to explain further . cheers

Comment: Here is a sample of my code that I am using. [editted fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KHFn8/5726/). @swornabsent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fiddle example is using Knockout 2.3. If you use Knockout 3+ you can use the textInput binding.

> The textInput binding links a text box () or text area () with a viewmodel property, providing two-way updates between the viewmodel property and the element’s value. Unlike the value binding, textInput provides instant updates from the DOM for all types of user input, including autocomplete, drag-and-drop, and clipboard events.

So instead of:

`<input data-bind='value: emailAddress,valueUpdate:"keyup"' required pattern="@"/>`

your binding would look like:

`<input data-bind='textInput: emailAddress' required pattern="@"/>`

Here is an updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mx45nnL6/2/

Comment: I am using textInput. But this is not solution to my problem.

Comment: If I can not use valueUpdate with only one value. I want to use blur or keydown. First time when user is typing, I don't want to show the error message. But next time if user is giving wrong value, message should show on keyup ( the way jquery validation works ). @79IT